angular: ionic how to use NavController.back() with replaceUrl true
I am wondering how to use
constructor(navCtrl: NavController)
this.navCtrl.back()
with
{replaceUrl: true}
in Ionic 8.
currently this replaceUrl option is not supported for back().
